# Calculate a rolling sum in an R data frame based on a date column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, zoo

I am looking to calculate a 3 month rolling sum of values in one column of a data frame (Input) based upon the dates in another column as per this reprex:

```
CusID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
Date <- c(ymd("2019-01-01"), ymd("2019-02-01"), ymd("2019-03-01"), ymd("2019-04-01"), ymd("2019-05-01"),
                 ymd("2019-01-06"),ymd("2019-04-07"),ymd("2019-06-15"))
Amount <- c(50,50,100,50,100,200,180,150)
Roll_3Mth <- c(50,100,200,200,250,200,180,330)
Input <-  data.frame(CusID, Date, Amount)
Output <- data.frame(CusID, Date, Amount, Roll_3Mth)
```

In this example, I wish to calculate the rolling sum by Group (CusID), over the preceding 3 months (inclusive of the Date value for the row being evaluated).  In the Output data frame I give the expected values.

How best to achieve this in R / Tidyverse without expanding to output a record for every date (as this will create a very large data frame for the periods being evaluated) - i.e. to use the data column for evaluating the period, and not counting back a fixed number of rows.  In my example the gaps between dates within each group are not consistent.

Would a package will Rcpproll or Zoo be able to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the rolling functions in `zoo` use a fixed integer window to calculate rolling operations. For every `Date` in `CusID` we can go back 3 months and calculate `Amount` which lie in between them.

```
library(dplyr)

Input %>%
  group_by(CusID) %>%
  mutate(Roll_3Mth = purrr::map_dbl(Date, 
                    ~sum(Amount[Date > (.x - months(3)) & Date <= .x])))


#  CusID Date       Amount Roll_3Mth
#  <dbl> <date>      <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     1 2019-01-01     50        50
#2     1 2019-02-01     50       100
#3     1 2019-03-01    100       200
#4     1 2019-04-01     50       200
#5     1 2019-05-01    100       250
#6     2 2019-01-06    200       200
#7     2 2019-04-07    180       180
#8     2 2019-06-15    150       330
```

Comment: Yes, it works on a small data set, but does not scale to large data.  On the same data set that I ran the zoo method on (340,000 records) I gave up and stopped the process after 20 minutes using the purrr approach (the basic zoo solution completed the task in about 7 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

**1)** The zoo package handles this using `rollapplyr` and a vector width.  Each element of the width is set to the number of components to sum and that can be readily set using `findInterval`.  (If `findInterval` is given a vector of dates as its first argument it returns for each such date the number of dates in the second argument, which must be sorted, that are less than it.)

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)

Input %>%
  group_by(CusID) %>%
  mutate(Roll_3Mth = 
    rollapplyr(Amount, width = 1:n() - findInterval( Date %m-% months(3), Date), sum)) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  CusID Date       Amount Roll_3Mth
  <dbl> <date>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1 2019-01-01     50        50
2     1 2019-02-01     50       100
3     1 2019-03-01    100       200
4     1 2019-04-01     50       200
5     1 2019-05-01    100       250
6     2 2019-01-06    200       200
7     2 2019-04-07    180       180
8     2 2019-06-15    150       330
```

**2)** Another approach is to convert Input to a wide form zoo object in which case we don't need the grouping.

```
z <- read.zoo(Input, split = "CusID", index = "Date")
tt <- time(z)
w <- 1:nrow(z) - findInterval( tt %m-% months(3), tt)
rollsumr(z, w, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
             1   2
2019-01-01  50   0
2019-01-06  50 200
2019-02-01 100 200
2019-03-01 200 200
2019-04-01 200 200
2019-04-07 200 180
2019-05-01 250 180
2019-06-15 150 330
```

Comment: Yes - this works and produces the expected results, but...

I have just scaled it on real data - 340,000 records - and it takes 7.5 minutes to execute on that data (versus about 1 minute when passing through that data with dplyr / tidyverse functions).

Wondering if there is a faster solution (I'll try that proposed below and check the speed) and also wondering if performance issues with zoo was the reason Rcpproll was written (have yet to try an Rcpproll solution).

Comment: The function is written in R rather than C and is quite general so there will be a speed penalty for that generality.  Also it converts everything to a zoo object under the hood since it is really meant to be used that way although it works without zoo objects as well.  I have just added a second approach converting to wide form and rolling on that which may or may not be faster.